# Where to join in multithreaded directory search?

Tags: c, multithreading, recursion, directory, thread-safety

I've been working on a multithreaded directory search that creates a thread everytime it runs into a new directory or file. So far the file threads are parallel and works fine, but I'm not sure where to join the new directory threads since it is recursive. I've tried putting it on the bottom of the function but it just creates a loop (not infinite but definitely wrong)

My code is below, I also have a pseudocode for ease of understanding.

For ease of explaining and clearing up the messy code, here is a pseudocode:

```
recursive function{
if (!(dir = opendir(ca->SD))){{
return;
}
while ((ptr = readdir(dir)) != NULL) {
    if (ptr->d_type == DT_DIR) { 
        if (strcmp(ptr->d_name, "..") == 0||strcmp(ptr->d_name, ".") == 0){
            continue;
        } 
        create thread/call recursive function
    }else(if file){
    create thread/call file handler function
    }
}
thread join for any live threads;
}
```

I'm just confused as to where to properly put the join for any of the directory threads. I currently keep getting some sort of loop.

Comment: `pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex);` then `if (pthread_self() == initialtid){...` with no `pthread_mutex_unlock()` after the `if` closes but with multiple calls to `pthread_mutex_unlock()` in the `if` statement itself is a recipe for disaster.

Answer (score 2):

I think you shoudn't try to create an unknown number of threads because It will have poorly performance. In this case it's better to use a pool of threads where you can control the maximum number of threads and you will not be creating and destroying threads for every directory entry.

Take a look on this [link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thread_pool) for information of what a pool of threads is.

In your example you have to wait for the threads termination at the end of each recursive call. I mean each call of `searchdirectory` should wait for the termination of the threads it created before returning.

Comment: Unfortunately the nature of the project requires a thread to be created for every directory, for an unknown amount of directories, so I am unable to do that.